# Existence of a function so an integral becomes null.

Tags: calculus, integration

Let E be an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ for example $E=[a,b]$. Let $A(s) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ a vector which components are real functions defined in E. How can I proof that there is a non-null real function $\beta (s)$ defined in E such that the integral:
$$
\int_E A(s) \beta (s) = 0
$$
is null? I think this is true in general, but I am not sure. If it isn't, what conditions are required for $A(s)$ for this to be true?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you want the coordinate functions of $A=(A_1, \dots, A_n)$ to be in $L^2(E)$. Then what you want is that
$$ \langle A_j, \beta \rangle =0 \qquad \forall j\in \{ 1, \dots, n\}. $$
So you are asking whether the orthogonal complement of $span\{A_1, \dots, A_n\}$ is nontrivial. This is indeed the case. You can see this as
$$ L^2(E)= span\{A_1, \dots, A_n\} \oplus span\{A_1, \dots, A_n\}^{\perp}.$$
However, $L^2(E)$ is infinite dimensional and $span\{A_1, \dots, A_n\}$ has dimension $n$, thus $span\{A_1, \dots, A_n\}^{\perp}$ is infinite dimensional (and therefore nontrivial).

I would guess that one can find weaker assumptions than $L^2(E)$, but I presumably then the proof gets more complicated.

Comment: I've deleted my answer, since its basically a duplicate of yours - it was an obvious enough answer I guess :)

Comment: @Sven-Ole Behrend There is no reason to delete your answer! You have presumably started before I posted. Different wording might help the OP to understand the answer better.

Comment: Yes! The coordinates are in fact in $L^2(E)$. Thank you to both of you, you've really helped me. I kind of forgot that what I wanted was just the scalar product of $L^2(E)$. However, if it is not a lot to ask, could you please give me a reference to the fact that $L^2(E)$ is infinite dimensional? I do know this, but I don't remember how to prove it. Once again, thank you!

Comment: @Guille All you need is to have infinitely many orthogonal functions. For $E=[0, 2\pi]$ you can take $f_n(x)=\sin(nx)$. For the general case you can just translate and rescale a bit.

Comment: Taking $n,m\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ we have after integrating twice by parts $$ \int_0^{2\pi} \sin(nx) \sin(mx) dx = \frac{m^2}{n^2} \int_0^{2\pi}\sin(nx) \sin(mx) dx.  $$ This tells you, that the scalar product of $f_n$ with $f_m$ vanishes for $m\neq n$. However, if they are orthogonal, then they are linearly independent and so you get that the space in question is infinite dimensional.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider the component-functions of A, which I will call $a_1, \dots, a_n$, you are searching for a function $\beta$, such that $\int_E a_i(s) \beta(s) \mathrm d s=0$ for all $i \in \mathbb N$. But the integral $\int_E a_i(s) \beta(s) \mathrm d s=0$ is just the scalar-product of the Hilbert space $L^2(E)$, so you are searching for a function, which is orthogonal with regard to this scalar-product to all $a_i$, which clearly exists, since the subspace spanned by the $a_i$ is finite.

If you know what a Hilbert space is, this should be a good enough answer, else I will try to elaborate more one this.

Comment: I like the way you think ;)

Comment: [+1] with a space (intended pun) between Hilbert and space.